How can I prevent Mathematica from using MathematicaSans font in output?
I'm trying to prepare some plots for publication using Mathematica 14.1. Although I give Mathematica the FontFamily->"Arial" option repeatedly in my code, it continues to use MathematicaSans and/or MathematicaSans-Bold fonts in the output. When I save the plots as PDF and then open in Adobe Illustrator, it gives a missing font error and prompts for replacement of these fonts. How can I force Mathematica to use Arial, Arial Bold, etc.? I'm not using any glyphs in my plots that aren't available in the Arial font family, so why is Mathematica picking a proprietary font?
Below is a pared-down example to demonstrate the issue (my actual plots source their data from an Excel spreadsheet instead of the Table commands in this toy example):
commonOptions[yaxisname_, aspectRatio_, imageSize_, imagePadding_, 
   axesFontSize_, legendFontSize_, legendPosition_, 
   dataLabels_] := {PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
   AspectRatio -> aspectRatio, ImageSize -> imageSize, 
   ImagePadding -> imagePadding, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize[10], FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
   TicksStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Black, 
      Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"]}, {GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed, 
      Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"]}}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[
      Text@Style[#, Bold, legendFontSize, FontFamily -> "Arial"] & /@ 
       dataLabels, LegendFunction -> Framed], legendPosition], 
   Frame -> True, 
   LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1.0], FontSize -> axesFontSize, 
     FontFamily -> "Arial"], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Text@
      Style["Time (min)", Bold, axesFontSize, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
     Text@Style[yaxisname, Bold, axesFontSize, 
       FontFamily -> "Arial"]}};

aspectRatio = 1;
imageSize = 300;
imagePadding = {{60, 20}, {55, 20}};
titleFontSize = 24;
axesFontSize = 18;
legendFontSize = 14;
firstPlot = 
  ListLinePlot[{Table[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}], 
    Table[Sin[0.98*t] + 0.1, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
    }, commonOptions["y-axis", aspectRatio, imageSize, imagePadding, 
    axesFontSize, 
    legendFontSize, {0.3, 0.25}, {"Data 1", "Data 2"}]];
secondPlot = 
  ListLinePlot[{Table[Cos[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}], 
    Table[Cos[0.934*t] - 0.02, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
    }, commonOptions["y-axis", aspectRatio, imageSize, imagePadding, 
    axesFontSize, legendFontSize, {0.6, 0.8}, {"Data 1", "Data 2"}]];
Labeled[GraphicsGrid[{{firstPlot, secondPlot}}, ImageSize -> 800, 
  Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Right, Bottom}, Spacings -> {20, 20}], 
 Style["Signals vs. Time", Bold, titleFontSize, 
  FontFamily -> "Arial"], Top, FrameMargins -> Tiny]

Output looks like this:

If I right-click on this graphic, pick "Save Graphic As...", and save it as a PDF, when I open the PDF in Illustrator, I get the missing font problem.
Below is a screenshot of what I see when opening the PDF in Adobe Illustrator:


PlotStyle is used for styling the plot itself (i.e., color of curve or points, shape of points, dashing, etc.). I use BaseStyle -> {FontSize[10], FontFamily -> "Arial"} as one of the options in Plot. This tends to work for me. Then, instead of using "Save Graphic As...", I export the plot programatically with something like Export["MyPlot.pdf", plot], where plot is the plot.

@march I gave that a try, but it didn't fix the problem. Mathematica is still using MathematicaSans and MathematicaSans-Bold for dashes and parentheses, despite adding the BaseStyle option to the plot commands as you specified.

Using an interactive ChatGPT session to troubleshoot, I found that wrapping the Style[ ] commands inside Text[ ] fixed the issue with those elements. The only thing I still can't get to use Arial font is the minus sign on the tick labels.

Have you tried TickStyle?

@MichaelE2 Yes, I've tried TicksStyle->{FontFamily->"Arial"}. I've also tried the same thing with BaseStyle, AxesStyle, and LabelStyle.

It is a bug. What else can be said or done than reporting to Wolfram?

I've discovered a minimal example that shows the substitution is internal to Export[]. Maybe there's a workaround: ImportString[   ExportString[Style["-1.0", FontFamily -> "Arial"], "PDF"],    "FormattedText"] // InputForm

I don't know if this can be used in a workaround: ImportString[ExportString[Style[\!\(\* TagBox[ StyleBox["\"\<\\[Dash]1.0\>\"", ShowSpecialCharacters->False, ShowStringCharacters->True, NumberMarks->True], FullForm]\), FontFamily -> "Arial"], "PDF"],    "FormattedText"] // InputForm

@azerbajdzan, you are making up bugs once again instead of understanding what is going on.

This issue has been mentioned several times, please use search: (1) How to avoid font substitution with Mathematica fonts?, (2) Some Characters From Custom Font Do Not Show Up, (3) Does PrivateFontOptions->{"OperatorSubstitution"->False} fail in version 10?

(4) Substituting Symbol font for Mathematica's custom font in exported plots and other graphics ...

@MichaelE2: ImportString[ExportString[Style["-$*%$&1.0", FontFamily -> "Arial", PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}], "PDF"], "FormattedText"] // InputForm

@Domen I did use search. Putting PrivateFontOptions->{"OperatorSubstitution"->False} in the BaseStyle for the plot is among the many things that I have tried which did not work.

@Domen Perhaps you should pay more attention to the OP question then writing comments with "solutions" that do not work. The links are just workarounds for a bug. So it is not like there is no bug and people are using code incorrectly. There is definitely a bug. The workarounds work in some situations in other they do not work. It seems that no of the workarounds work for OP's case. And I think the main reason is Labeled which is wrapped around the plots. I was able to use the workarounds for a plain plot but once it is inside Labeled it will not work. i.e. the Mathematica fonts are added.

@azerbajdzan I don't know why you think it's a bug. It's clearly an intentional design choice. A bug, if there is one, is in the workaround Export["/tmp/foo.pdf", plot, PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}], which does not work as in Domen's variation on my example. OTOH, I do agree with you that WRI is the best place to consult and report this to.

@MichaelE2 It is intentional design choice like if you ask a waiter for a meat with potatoes and he brings you meat with rice. You say him I told you I wanted it with potatoes, he would reply yes, but if you do not tell the cook he automatically replaces potatoes with rice. You would probably say to him you have a nice service design but I would say to him go to the cook and tell him what I told you what I want.

@Matt, it's always good to mention in your question similar posts that you've found and show how you used the solutions mentioned there :)

@azerbajdzan Seems a weak analogy. The advantage of the design choice is explained in the docs. There's no similar difference between rice and potatoes.

The core issue is the "OperatorSubstitution" setting.  But what's not obvious is that, if you set it from the outside, it can be overridden silently by internal styles.  The override that will happen here has to do with the FormatType of the graphic.  By default, FormatType->TraditionalForm, and that invokes the "TraditionalForm" style from the stylesheet which explicitly has "OperatorSubstitution"->True set.  This is not a bug...all of these individual behaviors are designed that way for good reasons...but the interactions of these conditions is leading to results that weren't the easiest to predict and which, for your use case, are undesirable.
So, let's fix your example by making some changes to your commonOptions setting...
commonOptions[yaxisname_, aspectRatio_, imageSize_, imagePadding_, 
   axesFontSize_, legendFontSize_, legendPosition_, 
   dataLabels_] := {PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
   AspectRatio -> aspectRatio, ImageSize -> imageSize, 
   ImagePadding -> imagePadding, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize[10], FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
   TicksStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Black, 
      Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"]}, {GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed, 
      Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial"]}}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[
      Text@Style[#, Bold, legendFontSize, FontFamily -> "Arial"] & /@ 
       dataLabels, LegendFunction -> Framed], legendPosition], 
   Frame -> True, 
   LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1.0], FontSize -> axesFontSize, 
     FontFamily -> "Arial", 
     PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False} (*** added ***)],
   FormatType -> TextForm,  (*** added ***)
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Text@
      Style["Time (min)", Bold, axesFontSize, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
     Text@Style[yaxisname, Bold, axesFontSize, 
       FontFamily -> "Arial"]}};

I've done two things here...

I've added the PrivateFontOptions setting to LabelStyle
I've added FormatType->TextForm as a top-level setting

That will entirely fix the graphics.  I see that you're wrapping the graphics in Labeled.  This style setting is internal to the graphics, and won't touch anything external.  In your particular example, the Labeled doesn't introduce any Wolfram fonts, but it could.  To account for that, you might just need to wrap a Style[] directive around the entire outer construct.  E.g.,
Style[Labeled[...], PrivateFontOptions->{"OperatorFontSubstutition"->False}]


(+1) Works on version 13.0.1.

That cures the problem with the font substitution on the minus signs in the ticks. The FormatType->TextForm caused the axes labels to display the word Text in the label, but that goes away if I just remove the Text@ in front of the Style options (it was getting wrapped with Text twice). I lose the Bold styling on the axes labels when the FormatType->TextForm is applied, but I can live with that.
